# Number theory notation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, modular-arithmetic

I am confused with the below notations .

I know that

($a \equiv b \mod {n} )\iff ( n|(a-b)$ )

but what the below notation says ?

$a = b \mod {n}$

and in theorem 16 in [this](http://www2.cs.uni-paderborn.de/cs/ag-bloemer/lehre/proseminar_WS2005/material/Volkhausen_Ausarbeitung.pdf?PHPSESSID=edd79a27cb022cfa749b4a2baa7ea6f0) ,it's given as below

if $g \in\mathbb{Z_n^*} ,  r_1,r_2 \in \mathbb{Z_n}$ and $m_1,m_2 \in \mathbb{Z_n}$

($g^{m_1}r_1^n =g^{m_2}r_2^n \mod {n^2}) \implies (g^{m_1-m_2}r_1^n=r_2^n \mod{n^2}$)

In the above equation , both sides are divided with $g^{m_2}$

When we can divide both sides of a modular expression as in the above equation with a number ?

Comment: When the number we are dividing by is relatively prime to the modulus.

Comment: You can use the Euclidean algorithm to see that "division" is legal when $gcd(g,n)=1$.

Comment: what this notation says 

$a=b \mod {n}$

Comment: @hanu $\ a = b\ {\rm mod}\ n\ $ could mean either $\ a\equiv b\pmod n\ $ or $\ a = (b\ {\rm mod}\ n),\,$ i.e.  the former combined with $\,0\le a < n.\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$g^{m_1}r_1^{n} \equiv g^{m_2}r_2^{n} \pmod {n^2} \Rightarrow n^2 \mid g^{m_1}r_1^{n} - g^{m_2}r_2^{n} \\ \Rightarrow n^2 \mid  g^{-m_2} \cdot (g^{m_1}r_1^{n} - g^{m_2}r_2^{n}) \Rightarrow n^2 \mid g^{m_1-m_2}r_1^n-r_2^n$$

**EDIT:**
We can multiply with $g^{-m_2}$,because, we know that $g \in \mathbb{Z}^*$,so it is a unit,therefore $g^{-1}$ exists.

In general, if $m \mid a-b \Rightarrow m \mid x(a-b), \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: but is $g^{-m_2} \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: I edited my answer..Tell me if you understand it now!!!

Comment: @hanu:  an inverse can be found using the Euclidean algorithm, as I indicated in my previous comment.

Comment: Yeah , understood . what about the notation $a=b \mod {n}$ , is it same as $a \equiv b \mod{n}$

Comment: Nice! it is the same,but it is better to write it like that :
$$a \equiv b \pmod n$$
because it isn't exactly an equality!!!We are working $\mod n$..